# Does xlswrite have limitations?

Tags: excel, matlab, file-writing

I'm running MATLAB R2017a. I am trying to execute a simple program that writes 3 characters to an Excel file.  When I run the program with a small number of values it is fine but when I increase it to the millions, the program pauses.

Does anyone know why the programming is pausing like this?

```
X = []    
filename = 'PopltnFL.xlsx';        
NumTrump = 4617886;    
NumClinton = 4504975;    
NumOther = 297025;    
*% Values for which program runs without puasing*    
% NumTrump = 4;
% NumClinton = 4;
% NumOther = 2;
%
for ii = 1:NumTrump
    X = [X,'T'];
end

for jj = 1:NumClinton
    X = [X,'C'];
end

for kk = 1:NumOther
    X = [X,'O'];
end

X = X';
xlswrite(filename,X)
```

Comment: What do you mean by a "pause"? Do you mean that your computer hangs? These are totally different things

Comment: BTW, you don't need loops, use `repmat('T', 1, NumTrump)`

Comment: and as @Justin hinted, I suspect the largest slowdown is actually created by MATLAB having to redimension this array `X` millions of time ... Your computer is probably coughing before it reaches the `xlswrite` statement.

Comment: besides, you are trying to write a column array of **9,419,886** rows, when the max number of rows in an Excel sheet is **1,048,576**. So to answer your question: YES, xlswrite is limited by the capabilities of Excel itself. Read more at [Excel specifications and limits](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)